# Mysql Query working like LEFT JOIN is not there

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with this mysql query. When I run it in phpmyadmin it shows only the "player_11" and the "player_11Count" . I can't join the players table. There are no errors shown. It acts just like the JOIN is not there. Do you have any ideas?

```
SELECT player_11, COUNT(player_11) AS player_11Count 
FROM user_teams 
LEFT JOIN players ON user_teams.player_11 = players.player_id 
WHERE round_id = '31' && user_teams.team_id = '22' 
GROUP BY player_11 
ORDER BY COUNT(player_11) DESC
```

Comment: Please help to make this a reproducible problem, by including sample data along with the current and expected output.

Comment: Add aliases to EACH column name in your query text. PS. `ON user_teams.player_11` Does the column named `player_11` exists really (and a bunch of `player_xx` with another numbers)? If so normalize your structure.

Comment: What table does round_id come from? You have round_id='31' in your where clause. If round_id is on players table then you are excluding all null round_id values from matched rows in the outer join.

Comment: we can't answer this without seeing the source data in the tables, and you also telling us what result you'd like your query to output when it reads that data. P.S. _it shows only the "player_11" and the "player_11Count"_ ...those are the only columns you asked it to show. So from that point o view it's unclear what the actual purpose o your join really is. Again that's why you need to show us the data and explain the result you are trying to achieve. We cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying to mysql "show me only player_11 and count(player_11)". You can't have anything else even with joining tables. Joining tables doesn't automatically select fields (unless your are using `SELECT *`)
You should say:

```
SELECT players.*, user_teams.player_11, COUNT(user_teams.player_11) AS player_11Count 
FROM user_teams .....
```

Then your players data will show up

Comment: you're assuming that's what the OP wants. But if you read the question, they haven't actually explained what they want. They've said there's a problem, but haven't told us what they were trying to achieve. So it's impossible to be sure what the correct query really is.